# How to avoid space after div in css?

Tags: html, css, divide

In the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bybt28p3/) there are some space getting appended below the content. When I inspect the element I get the `::after`. Could someone help with this? How can I get rid of this space?

```css
.grey_medium_font {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top: 0px none rgb(102, 102, 102);
    border-right: 0px none rgb(102, 102, 102);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left: 0px none rgb(102, 102, 102);
    /*font: normal normal normal normal 26px / 52.2px 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, sans-serif;*/
    font: normal normal normal normal 30px / 52.2px "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(102, 102, 102) none 0px;
    transition: border-color 0.1s ease 0s;
}/*#grey_medium_font*/
```

```html
<div class="row" style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 15px; width: 100%; height: 30%; background: #fdd;">
  <div class="feature  feature-icon-small col-sm-1">
    <i class="icon icon-tools"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h5 style="margin: 0;" class="grey_medium_font">Edit Post</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have added padding for topmost div. `padding-bottom: 15px;`. That is causing extra spaces to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weave: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#fe783d877f4a65b7f46d778514a26592

Look at your `div.row`

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 15px; width: 100%; height: 30%; background: #fdd;">
```

To fix the added padding on the bottom you need to remove `padding-bottom: 15px;`

Your problem is caused because padding is added to `.row` which is the parent container of your `grey_medium_font` class. Thus padding is added to the row and everything within the `.row` class in this case is inside the added padding.

**NOTE:** it's bad practice to add css in your HTML via the style tag. Keep your css in the css section and html in html. CSS should only be added via `<link rel="stylesheet" href="name.css">`. However there can be some exceptions to adding a `<style>` tag. This way it keeps your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

```css
.grey_medium_font {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 0 none rgb(102, 102, 102);
  border-right: 0px none rgb(102, 102, 102);
  border-bottom: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: 0 none rgb(102, 102, 102);
  font: normal normal normal normal 30px / 52.2px "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(102, 102, 102) none 0;
  transition: border-color 0.1s ease 0s;
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background: #fdd;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="feature feature-icon-small col-sm-1">
    <i class="icon icon-tools"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h5 class="grey_medium_font">Edit Post</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually this solved the problem. But in my original html file the space is not going away. May be due to some other css class. When I inspect I see `::after` before closing the div. I am not able to reproduce in js fiddle code snippet :( . if you have any alternate idea please suggest.

Comment: Based upon what I've seen in your code. You either have additional padding conflicting with either `.row, .col-sm-4, .grey_medium_font or h5`. It's also possible you have `border` affecting it as well. I can't give you a solid answer without an effective [pen](http://codepen.io/) or [weave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/) (There's also [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/))

Answer (score 2):

You can try to remove `padding-bottom:15px` from

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 0;width: 100%;height: 30%;background: #fdd;padding-bottom:15px">
```

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bybt28p3/2/),

Hope I solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have `padding-bottom 15px` for `div.row` and `border-bottom: 2px` for `h5.grey_medium_font`, try commenting out the border on `h5.grey_medium_font`